# Determining the best result given two variables

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics

I'm looking for a way to weight my results to get the "best" highest rated result.

I have a table consisting of rating (0-5), mentions and name.

I.E.

```
RATING   MENTIONS    NAME
2.5      15          Bob
4.4      14          Susan
1        60          John
5        2           Steve
```

Both mentions and rating are important so sorting by just rating won't get the desired results.

For this example; while Steve has the highest rating he has very little mentions so i'm not very confident that he is the "best" highest rated person. Susan has several mentions and a high rating so she should surpass Steve. John has a very low rating but lots of mentions, he should only surpass any of the other people if he has a ridiculous amount of mentions.

The ideal result would be something similar to

```
RATING   MENTIONS    NAME
4.4      14          Susan
5        2           Steve
2.5      15          Bob
1        60          John
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Look at this algorithm: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: Do you have the raw results as opposed to the summarized results?  At the very least, do you have the standard deviation?

Comment: I don't have the full results available, this is an abstract from the actual data but running standard deviation on Rating = 0.990402709 and Mentions = 33.82314815, does that help?

Comment: You don't want the overall standard deviation, you want it per name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing an appropriate statistical method for ranking. There are infinitely many ways to combine information, if you are looking for a way with a certain statistical property or utility, that's not really a programming problem. If you know what method you want but don't know how to implement it, that would be a better question for this site.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I put a CSV dump on drive https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qff7IhKNHyTbxj1RcsK9x2XsARgeVAyod4SPHR-FwWU/ if that helps. In the example above I renamed keywords to Name for simplification.

Comment: @Pim . . . If the summary had a standard deviation column, then you could use my method below (or Even Miller's stricter criteria).

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do this is

```
RATING * RATING * Mentions
```

Which would provide the following:

```
RATING   MENTIONS    NAME      SCORE
2.5      15          Bob       93.75
4.4      14          Susan     271.04
1        60          John      60
5        2           Steve     50
```

It is a pretty simple way to 'weight' the value of the rating.

Obviously you can go more complex but I would think the above is sufficient and the Query is easy so I will let you try and work that out yourself if you like the method!

Obviously you can just add another RATING if you want a LOT of weight on the rating OR multiply it by a a fixed amount - but the squaring / POWER is key (you could try `RATING ^ 2.5`) (^ is POWER)

Comment: This seems like a really bad example.  John pretty clearly has a lower rating than Steve, yet ranks higher.

Comment: Actually @GordonLinoff I would say even with a rating of 1, 60 mentions means that for some reason it is popular - it could be that it only has 1 rating from some troll and nobody else has rated the item. No weighting system will be perfect on two none-related items - hence why I put about using a different POWER until the desired effect occurs. What is the cut-off point 1000 mentions at 1 score, I don't know!!!!! WIth more data you could develop a better system (standard deviation etc. etc.) but with info provided I think the proposed solution balances simplicity with results.

Comment: . . I was assuming that `Mentions` really means `Number of ratings used for the average`.  If it means something else, then this approach might be quite reasonable.

Comment: exactly :-P - as always OP question leaves big gaps. hehe anyway +1ed your answer as with the right info SD is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter this problem, I often take the approach of reducing the rating by one standard error.  The formula for the standard error is:

```
standard deviation for the group / sqrt(group size)
```

If you had the standard deviation for each group, I would order them using:

```
order by (case when mentions > 1 then stdev / sqrt(mentions) end)
```

This is not as "punishing" as Evan Miller's suggestion (pointed to by Juergen).  This is essentially taking a confidence interval more like 60% than 95%.  Admittedly, my preference is a bit empirical (based on experience).  However, there is an issue with multiple comparisons and you don't need to estimate the exact confidence interval -- you just need to know the relative ordering of them.

You can calculate the standard deviation using the function `stdev()`.

Comment: Good answer if you have the data available to run the standard deviation! +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not very good in statistic, but from your expected result, I believe you need to find the importance of each property.. Which one is more important than the other one, I think you can use equation below:

```
values = weight * RATING + (1-weight) * MENTIONS
```

You can play around with the weight value, till you got what you want.. For me 0.8 kind a make sense..

```
RATING   MENTIONS    NAME      SCORE
4.4      14          Susan     6.32
2.5      15          Bob       5
5        2           Steve     4.4
1        60          John      2
```

Comment: Using Susan's data and a 0.8 as weight as you mentioned, (0.8 * 4.4 + (1-0.8) * 14) = 6.32, how did you get 5.72?

Comment: Oops, my bad.. hahaha